# Call Get and Set Function inside Object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm Studying a [book](https://www.inkling.com/store/book/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/?chapterId=2409a33726bb4e219bbfaa69ee210068)
but I don't understand the following.
I have an object like this

```
var serialnum = {
// This data property holds the next serial number.
// The $ in the property name hints that it is a private property. 
    $n: 10,
// Return the current value and increment it 
    get next() { 
        return this.$n++; 
    },

    // Set a new value of n, but only if it is larger than current 
    set next(n) {
    if (n >= this.$n) this.$n = n;
    else throw "serial number can only be set to a larger value"; 
    }    
};
```

- The `$` in the property name hints that it is a private property.

if I do `console.log(serialnum.$n);` i see 10. no private?

- Set Value
  if I do  `serialnum.next(100);` I have this error `Property 'next' of object #<Object> is not a function`
  if I do  `serialnum.$n = -100;` I Can set a value
- Get Value
  Ok, if i do `console.log(serialnum.next);` I retrieve the value

Comment: *"if I do console.log(serialnum.$n); i see 10. no private?"* JavaScript doesn't have the concept of private properties. Prepending the name with `$` is only a convention, as the comment already suggests: *"The $ in the property name **hints** that it is a private property"*. `serialnum.next` is a getter, so you have to call it as `var foo = serialnum.next`. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by passing an argument to it (it clearly doesn't accept an argument).

Comment: Thanks, i try to understand how can i use set...i can do serialnum.$n = -10 but in set i have if (n >= this.$n)

Comment: How can i use this? 
`set next(n) {
    if (n >= this.$n) this.$n = n;
    else throw "serial number can only be set to a larger value"; 
    }`

Comment: `serialnum.next = 11`

Comment: thanks! I was sure it was a trivial thing :), But why if I do

`serialnum.next = 10;
console.log(serialnum.next);`
I have 10 and not 11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it's done like this:

- Old way

  ```
  var serialnum = (function() {
      var $n = 10; // private
      return {
          next: function(n) {
              if (n === void(0)) return ++$n;
              if (n >= $n) return this.$n = n;
              throw "serial number can only be set to a larger value"; 
          }
      };
  })();
  serialnum.next();   // 11
  serialnum.next(15); // 15
  ```
- New way: getters and setters

  ```
  var serialnum = (function() {
      var $n = 10; // private
      return {
          get next() {
              return ++$n;
          },
          set next(n) {
              if (n >= $n) return $n = n;
              throw "serial number can only be set to a larger value"; 
          }
      };
  })();
  serialnum.next;      // 11
  serialnum.next = 15; // 15
  ```

Then, since `$n` is declared inside a function, it is a **private** variable - not accessible from outside.

But `next` is a **privileged method** (or has privileged getter and setter): since it's declared inside the function, it can read/write private variables; and since it is exported (returned) to the outside, it can be called from the outside.

Note that outside code can modify privileged methods, but without making them read/write private variables.

Also see [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: @PaulSantone You should use `++this.$n` instead of `this.$n++` in your getter ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gTjhg/1/)). Note that `++variable` increments and returns the new value; and `variable++` increments and returns the old value.

Comment: Thanks @Oriol ! Why you add (function() ?

Comment: @PaulSantone Because using a self-executing function I can make `$n` be a private variable of that function. Note `$n` isn't accessible from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

- The `$` in the property name **hints** that it is a private property, thats mean the `$` sign is just a coding convention to remind you when you use it.
- `Property 'next' of object #<Object> is not a function`: read about javascript getter/setter:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set
  - http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/